# Issues creating Xamarin IOS bindings library

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, cocoapods, objective-sharpie, pushy

I need to create a bindings library for the pushy framework from pushy.me

I have been going through this tutorial here.

http://blog.xhackers.co/xamarin-c-binding-of-a-cocoapods-ios-sdk-using-sharpie/

So I use the command "sharpie pod init Pushy"

this seems to work fine and I get the pod downloaded which has the pushy framework. I then use the command "sharpie pod bind" and it gives me an output Pods_ObjectiveSharpieIntegration.framework but there is no .a file associated with this. So from here I cant figure out how to import this into the xamarin ios project.

Any help would be awesome. Thanks this has been very confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open xxx/Pods/Pushy/PushySDK.framework ,the .a file is PushySDK (about 5M,there is no extension).

You can rename the file and then drag to the binding project

Comment: Ill accept this as the answer as its moved me a step up thank you. I just had 2 more questions.

I am getting this error on the apiDefinition.cs when i copy the code over.

"The type or namespace name "BaseType" could not be found"

'[BaseType (typeof(NSObject))]'
'[DisableDefaultCtor]'
'interface Pushy'
'{' I get the error on the DisableDefaultCtor as well.
@sunyt

Comment: see https://gist.github.com/unhappy224/ed76b8c054408f43ec04bc8b4c92a97a

Comment: Thank you you are amazing. Question though how did you figure out it needed those delegates, just wondering what i was missing as my output was missing those 2 lines. Wish I could give you more rep!

Comment: Since you seem to be mr bindings guru :p I'm getting a weird issue that i have asked here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42148530/xamarin-ios-bindings-dll-native-linker-cant-find-sdk

Comment: `Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult>` -> `delegate void BackgroundFetchResultHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult resutl);`

Comment: In case anyone needs it I have created a public git repo with the finished pushy sdk binding here https://github.com/dlawrence2060/IOSPushySDKBinding

Answer (score 1):

You can also bind frameworks. Xamarin has a guide for this. [Binding Native Frameworks](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/binding/objective-sharpie/platform-features/native-frameworks/)