# Xamarin ios bindings dll - Native linker cant find sdk

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, objective-sharpie, xamarin-binding, pushy

I'm attempting to bind the pushy.me obj-c framework. Ive run this through objective sharpie and get the output api definitons file and the framework.

From here I build the file and get the output "PushySDK.dll" and reference it in my xamarin.ios project. But when I attempt to build the project I get a compile error.

```
ugs-mobile-app/ugs_mobile_app.iOS/MTOUCH: Error MT5209: Native linking error: framework not found PushySDK (MT5209) (UGSMobileiOS)
```

I've been doing some googling but cant really find an exact reason for this to be happening.

I noticed in the build output under references this dll is referenced twice here.

```
Target _CompileToNative:
    MTouch Task
      AppBundleDir: bin/iPhone/Debug/build-iphone5.1-10.1.1/ugs_mobile_app.iOS.app
      AppExtensionReferences:
      AppManifest: bin/iPhone/Debug/build-iphone5.1-10.1.1/ugs_mobile_app.iOS.app/Info.plist
      Architectures: ARMv7
      ArchiveSymbols: <null>
      BitcodeEnabled: False
      CompiledEntitlements: obj/iPhone/Debug/build-iphone5.1-10.1.1/Entitlements.xcent
      Debug: True
      EnableGenericValueTypeSharing: True
      Entitlements: Entitlements.plist
      ExecutableName: ugs_mobile_app.iOS
      ExtraArgs: <null>
      FastDev: False
      HttpClientHandler: HttpClientHandler
      I18n: <null>
      IntermediateOutputPath: obj/iPhone/Debug/build-iphone5.1-10.1.1/mtouch-cache
      IsAppExtension: False
      LinkerDumpDependencies: False
      LinkMode: SdkOnly
      MainAssembly: /Users/derek/ugs-mobile-app/ugs-mobile-app/ugs_mobile_app.iOS/bin/iPhone/Debug//ugs_mobile_app.iOS.exe
      NativeReferences: <null>
      OutputPath: bin/iPhone/Debug/build-iphone5.1-10.1.1/
      Profiling: False
      ProjectDir: /Users/derek/ugs-mobile-app/ugs-mobile-app/ugs_mobile_app.iOS
      References:
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/System.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/System.Xml.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/System.Core.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Xamarin.iOS.dll
        ../../PushyIOSBindings/bin/Debug/PushySDK.dll
        /Users/derek/ugs-mobile-app/ugs-mobile-app/ugs_mobile_app/bin/Debug//ugs_mobile_app.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS//mscorlib.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/Microsoft.Win32.Registry.AccessControl.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/Microsoft.Win32.Registry.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.AppContext.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Collections.Concurrent.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Collections.NonGeneric.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Collections.Specialized.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Collections.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.ComponentModel.Primitives.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.ComponentModel.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Console.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Data.Common.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Data.SqlClient.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Diagnostics.Contracts.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Diagnostics.Process.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Diagnostics.TraceEvent.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Drawing.Primitives.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Dynamic.Runtime.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Globalization.Calendars.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Globalization.Extensions.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Globalization.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.IO.FileSystem.AccessControl.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.IO.FileSystem.DriveInfo.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.IO.FileSystem.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.IO.IsolatedStorage.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.IO.Pipes.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.IO.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Linq.Expressions.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Linq.Parallel.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Linq.Queryable.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Linq.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Net.AuthenticationManager.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Net.Cache.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Net.HttpListener.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Net.Mail.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Net.NameResolution.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Net.NetworkInformation.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Net.Ping.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Net.Primitives.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Net.Requests.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Net.Security.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Net.ServicePoint.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Net.Sockets.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Net.Utilities.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Net.WebSockets.Client.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Net.WebSockets.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.ObjectModel.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Reflection.Extensions.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Reflection.Primitives.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Reflection.TypeExtensions.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Reflection.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Resources.ReaderWriter.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.VisualC.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Runtime.Extensions.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Runtime.Handles.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Runtime.Numerics.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Runtime.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Security.AccessControl.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Security.Claims.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Security.Cryptography.Cng.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Security.Cryptography.Csp.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Security.Cryptography.DeriveBytes.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Security.Cryptography.Encryption.Aes.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Security.Cryptography.Encryption.ECDiffieHellman.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Security.Cryptography.Encryption.ECDsa.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Security.Cryptography.Encryption.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.Algorithms.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Security.Cryptography.RSA.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Security.Principal.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Security.SecureString.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.ServiceModel.Duplex.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.ServiceModel.Http.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.ServiceModel.NetTcp.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.ServiceModel.Primitives.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.ServiceModel.Security.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Text.Encoding.CodePages.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Text.Encoding.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Threading.AccessControl.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Threading.Overlapped.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Threading.Tasks.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Threading.Thread.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Threading.ThreadPool.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Threading.Timer.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Threading.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Xml.XDocument.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Xml.XPath.XDocument.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Xml.XPath.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Xml.XmlDocument.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Xml.XmlSerializer.dll
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Xml.Xsl.Primitives.dll
        ../../PushyIOSBindings/bin/Debug/PushySDK.dll
        /Users/derek/ugs-mobile-app/ugs-mobile-app/ugs_mobile_app/bin/Debug//ugs_mobile_app.dll
        /Users/derek/ugs-mobile-app/ugs-mobile-app/ugs_mobile_app/bin/Debug/Newtonsoft.Json.dll
        /Users/derek/ugs-mobile-app/ugs-mobile-app/ugs_mobile_app/bin/Debug/System.Net.Http.dll
        /Users/derek/ugs-mobile-app/ugs-mobile-app/ugs_mobile_app/bin/Debug/System.Net.Http.Primitives.dll
```

Here is the error the build logs gives.

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang  -framework Foundation -framework CloudKit -framework QuartzCore -framework CoreGraphics -framework UIKit -framework WebKit -F /Users/derek/ugs-mobile-app/ugs-mobile-app/ugs_mobile_app.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/build-iphone5.1-10.1.1/mtouch-cache -framework PushySDK -weak_framework CFNetwork -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.3.1.8/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.a /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.3.1.8/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/lib/libxamarin-debug.a /Users/derek/ugs-mobile-app/ugs-mobile-app/ugs_mobile_app.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/build-iphone5.1-10.1.1/mtouch-cache/ugs_mobile_app.iOS.exe.armv7.o /Users/derek/ugs-mobile-app/ugs-mobile-app/ugs_mobile_app.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/build-iphone5.1-10.1.1/mtouch-cache/Xamarin.iOS.dll.armv7.o /Users/derek/ugs-mobile-app/ugs-mobile-app/ugs_mobile_app.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/build-iphone5.1-10.1.1/mtouch-cache/mscorlib.dll.armv7.o /Users/derek/ugs-mobile-app/ugs-mobile-app/ugs_mobile_app.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/build-iphone5.1-10.1.1/mtouch-cache/System.dll.armv7.o /Users/derek/ugs-mobile-app/ugs-mobile-app/ugs_mobile_app.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/build-iphone5.1-10.1.1/mtouch-cache/PushySDK.dll.armv7.o /Users/derek/ugs-mobile-app/ugs-mobile-app/ugs_mobile_app.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/build-iphone5.1-10.1.1/mtouch-cache/registrar.armv7.o /Users/derek/ugs-mobile-app/ugs-mobile-app/ugs_mobile_app.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/build-iphone5.1-10.1.1/mtouch-cache/main.armv7.o -force_load /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.3.1.8/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/lib/libapp.a -Wl,-pie -arch armv7 -miphoneos-version-min=8.1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.2.sdk -lz -o /Users/derek/ugs-mobile-app/ugs-mobile-app/ugs_mobile_app.iOS/bin/iPhone/Debug/build-iphone5.1-10.1.1/ugs_mobile_app.iOS.app/ugs_mobile_app.iOS -liconv -u _UIApplicationMain -u _xamarin_get_block_descriptor -u _xamarin_timezone_get_data -u _xamarin_log -u _mono_pmip
    Process exited with code 1, command:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang  -framework Foundation -framework CloudKit -framework QuartzCore -framework CoreGraphics -framework UIKit -framework WebKit -F /Users/derek/ugs-mobile-app/ugs-mobile-app/ugs_mobile_app.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/build-iphone5.1-10.1.1/mtouch-cache -framework PushySDK -weak_framework CFNetwork -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.3.1.8/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.a /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.3.1.8/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/lib/libxamarin-debug.a /Users/derek/ugs-mobile-app/ugs-mobile-app/ugs_mobile_app.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/build-iphone5.1-10.1.1/mtouch-cache/ugs_mobile_app.iOS.exe.armv7.o /Users/derek/ugs-mobile-app/ugs-mobile-app/ugs_mobile_app.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/build-iphone5.1-10.1.1/mtouch-cache/Xamarin.iOS.dll.armv7.o /Users/derek/ugs-mobile-app/ugs-mobile-app/ugs_mobile_app.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/build-iphone5.1-10.1.1/mtouch-cache/mscorlib.dll.armv7.o /Users/derek/ugs-mobile-app/ugs-mobile-app/ugs_mobile_app.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/build-iphone5.1-10.1.1/mtouch-cache/System.dll.armv7.o /Users/derek/ugs-mobile-app/ugs-mobile-app/ugs_mobile_app.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/build-iphone5.1-10.1.1/mtouch-cache/PushySDK.dll.armv7.o /Users/derek/ugs-mobile-app/ugs-mobile-app/ugs_mobile_app.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/build-iphone5.1-10.1.1/mtouch-cache/registrar.armv7.o /Users/derek/ugs-mobile-app/ugs-mobile-app/ugs_mobile_app.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/build-iphone5.1-10.1.1/mtouch-cache/main.armv7.o -force_load /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.3.1.8/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/lib/libapp.a -Wl,-pie -arch armv7 -miphoneos-version-min=8.1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.2.sdk -lz -o /Users/derek/ugs-mobile-app/ugs-mobile-app/ugs_mobile_app.iOS/bin/iPhone/Debug/build-iphone5.1-10.1.1/ugs_mobile_app.iOS.app/ugs_mobile_app.iOS -liconv -u _UIApplicationMain -u _xamarin_get_block_descriptor -u _xamarin_timezone_get_data -u _xamarin_log -u _mono_pmip
    ld: framework not found PushySDK
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

MTOUCH: error MT5209: Native linking error: framework not found PushySDK
MTOUCH: error MT5202: Native linking failed. Please review the build log.
Task "MTouch" execution -- FAILED
Done building target "_CompileToNative" in project "/Users/derek/ugs-mobile-app/ugs-mobile-app/ugs_mobile_app.iOS/UGSMobileiOS.csproj".-- FAILED

Done building project "/Users/derek/ugs-mobile-app/ugs-mobile-app/ugs_mobile_app.iOS/UGSMobileiOS.csproj".-- FAILED
```

I have also tried just adding the bindings project as a reference and I get the same issue. I am totally unclear on whats causing this error and any help is appreciated. Thanks

EDIT: I have added these flags to the "additional mtouch arguments"

```
-gcc_flags "-L${ProjectDir} -lPushySDK -force_load ${ProjectDir}/../../PushyIOSBindings/Binding/PushySDK.framework/PushySDK.a"
```

Comment: Do you edit iOS Build's Extra argument ?

Comment: You are talking about the extra mtouch arguments correct as thats where I added this line.
-gcc_flags "-L${ProjectDir} -lPushySDK -force_load ${ProjectDir}/../../PushyIOSBindings/Binding/PushySDK.framework/PushySDK.a" @sunyt

Comment: Try to delete this line

Comment: I deleted this line from the addition arguments and still get the error. Do I need to include the original .framework folder or the .a file in the xamarin.ios project? @sunyt

Comment: dont need to do that

Comment: Okay, not sure where to go from here. Thanks again for all the help so far.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135334/discussion-between-derek-lawrence-and-sunyt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here was I was using a swift framework and needed to include the swift libraries and packages. There are nuget packages that need to be added to the project as well as the libary files for all the swift libraries need to be manually added into a "frameworks" folder at the root of the project.